# Looking for a working example of JasperStudio xml subdatasource

Tags: xml, jasper-reports

I have scoured here and Jasper and cannot find a downloadable, working example of using an xml subdatasource. I understand the issues regarding having to cast and such but am not familiar enough with Jasper to know what I am doing wrong what with various notes all over the place. So if I had XML that looked like...

```
<a>
    <b>
    <c>
       <d>
       <e>
    </c>
    <f>
</a>
```

I can easily make a parent report on /a that provides b and f. But all my attempts to build a sub report using subdatasource (on /a/c) have failed. If anyone has one that is pretty simple and works it would be much appreciated because I seriously cannot find a working example on the web - even the Jasper 6.2 sample code is built using a different mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

To pass a subDataSource to a subreport, you need to add a Data Source Expression to it.

This expression is usually a call to one of the API methods of the JRXmlDataSource: `dataSource([...])` or `subDataSource([...])` as described in the javadoc here: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRXmlDataSource.html#method_summary

You can add/edit a Data Source Expression either manually or with the help of JasperSoft Studio (JSS). In both cases, the assumption is that you are already iterating over "a" type nodes from your XML.

When working with JSS, just edit the Subreport property "Data Source Expression" with this expression:

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE})
.subDataSource("/c")
```

The expression can be shorter if you import the class in your report from within report's advanced properties, usually on this path: Misc > Imports

If you choose to manually do this, then you should have something resembling this in your JRXML:

```
<jasperReport ...>
  <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource"/>
  ...

  <subreport>
    <reportElement .../>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[
      ((JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/c")
    ]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["path/to/subreport"]]></subreportExpression>
  </subreport>

  ...
</jasperReport>
```

With a couple of modifications you can have the JasperReports xmldatasource sample work with a sub data source:

Step #1. Make sure that CustomersReport.jrxml contains only this code for the subreport part:

```
<subreport>
      <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="5" y="25" width="507" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#FFCC99" uuid="e7de82f1-2e1c-4459-bef3-307e57903e0b"/>
      <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[
        ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/Northwind/Orders[CustomerID='" + $F{CustomerID} + "']")
      ]]></dataSourceExpression>
      <subreportExpression><![CDATA["OrdersReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Step #2. In OrdersReport.jrxml make sure that:

- you remove the CustomerID parameter
- your XPATH query looks like this: `<queryString language="xPath"><![CDATA[Orders]]></queryString>`

Important note:
In this case, I used the `dataSource(expr)` method of the JRXmlDataSource because the Customers and Orders are siblings in the XML file.
If Orders had been per Customer(nested within Customers) I would have probably used the `subDataSource("Orders")` approach.

Comment: Narcis - thanks for this but it is not working for me - hence the request for a working example.

Comment: One confusion I have is that the documentation implies that the subDataSource reference should be (in my case) "booking/customer" but it also says that it is based on the current XML node which is a booking node so perhaps it should just be "customer" (per your example) but if that were the case why would it need to be qualified with [booking_id= per your very last sentence.

Comment: You are right, I have introduced some confusion with my answer. I have added some minor clarifications and corrected the subDataSource API calls for both the answer and the sample. Thank you